# Relative reference in table breaking when new row is inserted in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-tables

Any guidance is appreciated.

Scenario: Trying to create a dynamic pie chart which excludes zeros from data and legend.

Problem: I created a table and wrote the formula to filter zero value for the data range. It works fine but when a new row is inserted in the table, the row formula in temp part 2 column in excel is not taking relative reference of a particular row. Instead, it is taking the row number where clicked on insert>row>below.
For example, I inserted the new row at row  30, 31 but it takes D32 as a relative reference instead of D30, D31.

It works fine if i delete the current formula and drag and drop all the formula from the first row till last row, not sure why it mess up when new row is inserted.[Excle file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HFMQU2TouklENO621JFToVWIH7thcNma/view?usp=sharing)

Let me know if the question doesn't make sense, i have snapshot the issue.

[image: releative reference is taking last row number instead of actual row number]

Answer (score 0):

This formula solution work in Excel sheet

In `F6`, copied down:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$6:$B$31)/(C$6:C$31>0),ROW(A1))),"")
```

In `G6`, copied down :

```
=IF(F6="","",INDEX(B:B,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($B$6:$B$31)/(C$6:C$31=F6),COUNTIF(F$6:F6,F6))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated your solution.